# function pointer member variable

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I have a member variable in a class of type double (*)(double) but there are some functions id like to store that have a 2nd default parameter so they're double (*)(double, double) so I can't store it in my current member variable.

Is it possible for me to make my member variable a double (*)(double, double) so it could also store a (*)(double)? Is there any different approach that could accomplish what I want? Or would I need 2 different variables for the case where its using 2 parameters vs 1?

Comment: Please show the code that you're referring to, instead of just describing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two variables. The number of arguments in the call has to match the number of arguments in the function pointer variable, so you can't use the same variable for a different number of arguments.

If you only need one of them at a time, you can save space in the structure by using a union.

```
double somefunc(double);
double otherfunc(double, double);

struct mystruct {
    union {
        double(*onearg)(double);
        double(*twoarg)(double, double);
    } func
    // other members
};

mystruct obj;

obj.func.onearg = somefunc;
double foo = obj.func.onearg(1.2);
obj.func.twoarg = otherfunc;
double bar = obj.func.twoarg(2.5, 11.1);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do! Would you explain how this saves on space, please? I've never used a union before.

Comment: A union uses the same memory for both members. You can only read the last member that you wrote to it.